# How to repeat a row for each value of its corresponding column

Tags: linux, awk, sed, perl

I want to repeat a row for  all its corresponding values  any help

my input file is like this

```
    pos     COL1  COL2  COL3
    18691441    C   A   G
    18691572    G   C   G
    18691620    A   T   G
    18691716    C   G   C
```

i want output like this

```
pos COL1    
18691441    COL1 C  
18691441    COL2 A  
18691441    COL3 G  
18691572    COL1 G  
18691572    COL2 C  
18691572    COL3 G  
18691620    COL1 A  
18691620    COL2 T  
18691620    COL3 G  
18691716    COL1 C  
18691716    COL2 G  
18691716    COL3 C
```

i am trying to repeat a row but it simply makes them duplicate , i am using

```
while read line; do for i in {1..3}; do echo "$line"; done; done < real2.txt
```

and gives output:

```
pos       COL1 COL2 COL3
18691441    C   A   G
18691441    C   A   G
18691441    C   A   G
18691572    G   C   G
18691572    G   C   G
18691572    G   C   G
18691620    A   T   G
18691620    A   T   G
18691620    A   T   G
18691716    C   G   C
18691716    C   G   C
18691716    C   G   C
```

then i extracted pos from  input 1.txt file and make 1_pos.txt and write something like this:

```
     pos
    18691441
    18691572
    18691620
    18691716
    for i in `cat 1_post.txt`;
    do
   x=$(grep -i "^$i" 1.txt | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1"\t""COL1""\t"$2}' ) ;
   y=$(grep -i "^$i" 1.txt | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1"\t""COL2""\t"$3}' ) ;
   z=$(grep -i "^$i" 1.txt | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1"\t""COL3""\t"$4}' ) ;

    echo -e "$x""\n""$y""\n""$z";
    done
```

this gives me output, with column information, but what if i have 405 columns  instead of three i do not want to repeat lines for each column 405 times, i try to put this in loop but it does not work :

```
18691441    COL1    C
18691441    COL2    A
18691441    COL3    G
18691572    COL1    G
18691572    COL2    C
18691572    COL3    G
18691620    COL1    A
18691620    COL2    T
18691620    COL3    G
18691716    COL1    C
18691716    COL2    G
18691716    COL3    C
```

Answer (score 2):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";print "pos" OFS "COL1"}{if(NR==1){for(f=2;f<=NF;f++) c[f]=$f;}
     else{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,c[i],$i}}' real2.txt
```

The output:

```
pos     COL1
18691441        COL1    C
18691441        COL2    A
18691441        COL3    G
18691572        COL1    G
18691572        COL2    C
18691572        COL3    G
18691620        COL1    A
18691620        COL2    T
18691620        COL3    G
18691716        COL1    C
18691716        COL2    G
18691716        COL3    C
```

---

`OFS="\t"` - output field separator

`print "pos" OFS "COL1"` - prints *header* line

`if(NR==1){for(f=2;f<=NF;f++) c[f]=$f;` - collecting column names from the first/header line

`for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1, c[i], $i` - printing each column (`COL...`) value "rowwise" regarding to respective `pos` column value and its corresponding column name.

Comment: thanks @Roman , but i a trying to add columns names too , any help

Comment: @a.k, ok, see my update

Comment: thanks a lot @Roman, can its works same for 405 columns rather than this 3 , in actual file i have 405 columns , i am trying to put loop over it but it does not work , can i have looping for 405 columns , thanks in advance.

Comment: @a.k, can you share at least few lines from the 
actual file with those 405 columns via free file hosting service?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
while read line col1 col2 col3; 
do 
    if [[ "$line" = "pos" ]]; then
        echo "pos COL"
        continue    
    fi
    echo "$line COL1 $col1"  
    echo "$line COL2 $col2"  
    echo "$line COL3 $col3"  
done < real2.txt
```

output:

```
pos COL
18691441 COL1 C
18691441 COL2 A
18691441 COL3 G
18691572 COL1 G
18691572 COL2 C
18691572 COL3 G
18691620 COL1 A
18691620 COL2 T
18691620 COL3 G
18691716 COL1 C
18691716 COL2 G
18691716 COL3 C
```

Comment: thanks @jacek , its pretty cool, can we have same code in loop for 405 columns rather than this 3, thanks in advance

Comment: It is possible but in that case Stéphane Chazelas answer is much better solution.

Answer (score 2):

[Don't use shell loops to process text.](/q/169716)

Here, `awk` is the right tool for the task. But you only need to call it once:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
  NR == 1 {print $1, "name", "value"; split($0, header); next}
  {for (i = 2; i < NF; i++) print $1, header[i], $i}' < your-file
```

<sub><sup>(a variation on [Roman's answer](/a/364086))</sup></sub>

Comment: thanks @Stephane , it work well for 2 repetition , as output:                        pos name value
18691441 COL1 C
18691441 COL2 A
18691572 COL1 G
18691572 COL2 C
18691620 COL1 A
18691620 COL2 T
18691716 COL1 C
18691716 COL2 G
 what if it needs for 405 columns instead of 3

Comment: @a.k, then it should work as long as the input file is in the same format (including the header line with its 405 column names)

Comment: thanks a lot  @Stephane , it works pretty well. can you just explain the steps.

Answer (score 1):

```
while IFS= read -r l; do
   read -r -a A <<<"$l"
   case $l in
      'pos'[\ \   ]* )
         echo "${A[@]:0:2}"
         C=("${A[@]:1}")
         ;;

      * )
         p=0 x=${A[0]}
         for e in "${A[@]:1}"; do
            echo "$x ${C[$p]} $e"
            ((p++))
         done
         ;;
   esac
done < yourfile


sed -E '
   /\n/bloop

   y/\t/ /;s/  +/ /g;s/^ +//;s/ +$//

   1{
      h
         s/ /\n/2
      x
         s/ /\n/;s/.*\n//
      x
         s/\n.*//
      b
   }

   G;s/\n/ &/

   :loop
      #  1     2     3   4   5
      s/^(\S+ )(\S+) (.*)(\n)(\S+) ?/\1\5 \2\4\1\3\4/
      /\n$/{
         /\n.*\n/!d
      }
       P
      /\n.*\n/D
   tloop

' yourfile
```

---

### Results

```
pos COL1
18691441 COL1 C
18691441 COL2 A
18691441 COL3 G
18691572 COL1 G
18691572 COL2 C
18691572 COL3 G
18691620 COL1 A
18691620 COL2 T
18691620 COL3 G
18691716 COL1 C
18691716 COL2 G
18691716 COL3 C
```

---

### Explanation

- First off, we convert any residual TABs to spaces, then squeeze multiple spaces, and finally trim any leading/trailing spaces.
- We do a special handling of the first line:

  - a) make a copy of the line.
  - b) mark the end of the 2nd column for later.
  - c) interchange this marked line with the copy stored in hold space.
  - d) strip the first column, then revert back & in that display cols1,2.
- For all the other lines, (2 to eof) we append the column names to the line.
- Then setup a `do-while` loop in which in every iteration we rearrange the fields in the manner shown so that the column name alongwith it's value is printed out. We stop when we see a line having `\n` at it's end AND it's the only `\n` char remaining in the line. Otherwise, we just chop off the the leading portion and branch back to the loop beginning.

Comment: thanks @Rakesh Sharma , but i want to add columns names too.