# How to split multiple column into two columns based on the first column

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a tab delimited column text  like below

```
A    1   12  13
B    3   4   5 
C    6   17   8
D    19   10  11
```

how could I convert the above table like below

```
A    1
A    12
A    13
B    3
B    4
B    5
C    6
C    17
.
.
.
```

Comment: `B` column has value `\t3`. Why has it been missed from the result?

Comment: Almost identical [How to repeat a row for each value of its corresponding column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364085/how-to-repeat-a-row-for-each-value-of-its-corresponding-column)

Answer (score 4):

With awk:

```
$ awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$i}' file
A 1
A 12
A 13
B 3
B 4
B 5
C 6
C 17
C 8
D 19
D 10
D 11
```

To have the output tab delimited, you can use the `OFS` variable:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$i}' file
A   1
A   12
A   13
B   3
B   4
B   5
C   6
C   17
C   8
D   19
D   10
D   11
```